# Column names in each table must be unique (EF6)

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am trying to convert Shopify products scheme into a EF6 model and update the database. For some reason, when I try to run the command: "update-database", EF6 gives me this error:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Product_id' in table 'Options' is specified more than once.

And it indeed generates the following SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Images] (
[id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[product_id] [nvarchar](max),
[position] [int] NOT NULL,
[created_at] [nvarchar](max),
[updated_at] [nvarchar](max),
[src] [nvarchar](max),
[Product_id] [nvarchar](128),
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Images] PRIMARY KEY ([id])
```

As you can see it has two fields for product ID. And I have no idea where it got the second one from.

Here is some of the classes I generated from the Shopify json scheme:

```
 public class Product
 {
    //ProductId for EF use
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    //shopify product id
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string body_html { get; set; }
    public string vendor { get; set; }
    public string product_type { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string handle { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string published_at { get; set; }
    public string template_suffix { get; set; }
    public string published_scope { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public List<Variant> variants { get; set; }
    public List<Option> options { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
    public Image2 image { get; set; }
}
 public class Image
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    //public string product_id { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string src { get; set; }
    public List<string> variant_ids { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have that field already present in your migrations file?

Comment: The error mentions an options table. What's its model or do you have fluent code?